# Adding jQuery rails 6.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I'm trying to set up jQuery in rails 6.1 but I'm running into errors but I believe it's set up correctly.

I've done the following:

1. Added `yarn add jquery`

2 In `config/webpack/environments.js` I have

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const erb = require('./loaders/erb');
const webpack = require("webpack");

environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
}));

environment.loaders.prepend('erb', erb);
module.exports = environment;
```

3. In `packs/application.js` I have the following

```
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.

import 'core-js/stable'
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'

import Rails from '@rails/ujs';
import Turbolinks from 'turbolinks';
import * as ActiveStorage from '@rails/activestorage';
import 'channels';

Rails.start();
Turbolinks.start();
ActiveStorage.start();

import('jquery');
import('./main.js');
import('./lib_ext.js');
import('./dialog.js');
import('./widgets.js');
import('./classes.js');
import('./payroll.js');
import('./account_context_menu.js');
import('./plan_table.js');
import('./requirements.js');
import('./help.js');
import('./help_data.js');
import('./scripts.js');
import('./additional.js');
import('./effects.js');
import('./consolidated_orders');
import('./sales_invoices.js');
import('./journals/auto_reversal.js');
import('./budgets/new.js');
import('./budgets/export.js');

import('../stylesheets/application.scss');
const images = require.context('../images', true)
```

Here are the errors I'm getting
[image]

For example, the error in requrements.js is targeting this line
`ReqWorksOrder.prototype = {`

[image]

Any help here would be great.

Here is my `package.json`

```
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jquery-confirm": "^3.3.4",
    "jquery-debounced-and-throttled-resize": "^1.0.1",
    "jquery-powertip": "^1.3.1",
    "jquery-treegrid-webpack": "^0.0.2",
    "jquery-treetable": "^3.2.0-1",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "jquery-ui-touch-punch": "^0.2.3",
    "jquery.customSelect": "^0.5.2",
    "jquery.scrollto": "^2.1.3",
    "jquery.ui.widget": "^1.10.3",
    "jstree": "^3.3.11",
```

Comment: btw, why are doing this?
if you must to do, create new project with rails 5 and create new project with rails 6 (without webpacker). Then change rails 6 project to rails 5. (ex. adding assets/application.js etc.)

Answer (score 0):

adding as an answer to include code blocks:

on my working system, this is my `config/webpack/environment.js`:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

// Older Rails6/Yarn
const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.append('Provide',
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        Popper: ['popper.js', '@popperjs/core', 'default']
    })
)

// Newer Rails6/Yarn
environment.loaders.append('expose', {
    test: require.resolve('jquery'),
    loader: 'expose-loader',
    options: {
        exposes: ['$', 'jquery'],
    }
});

module.exports = environment;
```

can you try that and see if it helps?